# Ionic v3 strange issue

Tags: ionic-framework, navigation, ionic3

Dear all ionic developers.

Please help me with the issue which I have never seen before. The issue is when the page comes from multiple redirects then some of the features on the page are not working properly. Like segment, rating form, form validation. It starts working when I rotate or resize the device manually (In Browser) and it reflects the changes.

When I first log in and the page redirected to a Home page, the segment on the home page is not working but when I open the home page from the side menu then it’s working. Same issue on the Rating form page.

Not getting what’s the issue because there is no error in console. Please help me if someone has the same issue before.

Here is the output of the ionic info

**Ionic:**

ionic (Ionic CLI) : 4.6.0
Ionic Framework : ionic-angular 3.9.2
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.1

**Cordova:**

cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
Cordova Platforms : android 7.0.0, ios 4.5.5
Cordova Plugins : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 1.2.1, (and 4 other plugins)

**System:**

Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (C:\android\sdk)
NodeJS : v10.15.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
npm : 6.4.1
OS : Windows 7

Please help me to fix this.

Comment: You tried clearing your browser cache? This is in `ionic serve` right?

Comment: It is functionality or ui related issue. but you can try ChangeDetectorRef from ionic.
use this.changeDetectorRef .detectChanges();
after completion of particular code, that is not working.

Comment: This is pretty vague without seeing a code snippet or a repo. Try removing some of that functionality until normal behavior returns to isolate the component which may cause the problems.